# MySQL delete all but one record matching two column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am cleaning up data in a MySQL database.

I would like to find rows that have the same "picture_id" value and a "date" value of "13-Jul-18". I would then like to delete all but ONE of the record matches for each picture_id.

Example:

```
id: 1 picture_id: 2 date: "13-Jul-18" followers: 4553
id: 2 picture_id: 2 date: "13-Jul-18" followers: 4552
id: 3 picture_id: 2 date: "13-Jul-18" followers: 4557
id: 4 picture_id: 2 date: "13-Jul-18" followers: 4577

id: 5 picture_id: 3 date: "13-Jul-18" followers: 4355
id: 6 picture_id: 3 date: "13-Jul-18" followers: 4351
id: 7 picture_id: 3 date: "13-Jul-18" followers: 4353
id: 8 picture_id: 3 date: "13-Jul-18" followers: 4374
```

would return:

```
id: 4 picture_id: 2 date: "13-Jul-18" followers: 4577
id: 8 picture_id: 3 date: "13-Jul-18" followers: 4374
```

It doesn't matter which of the records get deleted, only that there is one record left over after deleting for each picture_id.

Table Structure:

```
id
picture_id
date
followers
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
DELETE FROM `pictures` WHERE `date` = '13-Jul-18'
```

How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: So what I understood is , you want to delete all record for **13-Jul-18** and for each id within the given data max Id should be kept and remaining all should be deleted right ?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't matter which Id of the duplicates that are kept. It only matters that one of each picture_id is left

Comment: "Yes, but it doesn't matter which Id of the duplicates that are kept. It only matters that one of each picture_id is left" Did both (topicstarter and @AlpeshJikadra) off you check the duplication link that @GordonLinoff provided?  His answer in that links does precisely that it keeps the first one of each duplicate..

Comment: Hi I have replied to your existing duplication question.